# Call ioctl with SIOGCSIWFREQ return 0 but don't change frequency

Tags: c, linux, networking, ioctl

Hi i'm wroting something about network interfaces managment just to spend time. 
I wrote a functions in c that make me able to put down or up a interface or, talking about wlan interfaces, to change mode like monitor managed etc. Now i want to change the the listening channel of the wlan interface, so i surfed on the net and i found different solution like using the nl80211 etc. The most intersting one in my opinion is the one with ioctl. So i wrote these pieces of code

```
int changeChannel(int handler,int channel){
  getChannel(handler);
  wreq.u.freq.m=  RETRIEVE_FREQ(channel);
  wreq.u.freq.e = 6;


  short app = ioctl(sock,SIOCSIWFREQ,&wreq);
  if(app<0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error to change the on %i channel to %s\n",channel,interfaces[handler]);
    return app;
  }
}

int getChannel(int handler){
  iw_get(handler);
  register short app =ioctl(sock,SIOCGIWFREQ,&wreq);
  if(app<0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error to get the channel from %s\n",interfaces[handler]);
    return app;
  }

  return RETRIEVE_CHANNEL(wreq.u.freq.m);
}
```

where RETRIEVE_CHANNEL and RETRIEVE_FREQ are macros that i use to get the channel from the freq and the freq from the channel. 
Defined as follow

```
#define RETRIEVE_CHANNEL(freq) ({\
int _channel = -1;\
switch(freq){\
    case CHANNEL1:\
        _channel = 1;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL2:\
        _channel = 2;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL3:\
        _channel = 3;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL4:\
        _channel = 4;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL5:\
        _channel = 5;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL6:\
        _channel = 6;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL7:\
        _channel = 7;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL8:\
        _channel = 8;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL9 :\
        _channel = 9;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL10:\
        _channel = 10;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL11:\
        _channel = 11;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL12:\
        _channel = 12;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL13:\
        _channel = 13;\
        break;\
    case CHANNEL14:\
        _channel = 14;\
        break;\
}\
_channel;\
});
#define RETRIEVE_FREQ(channel) ({\
    int _freq = -1;\
    switch(channel){ \
        case 1:\
            _freq = CHANNEL1;\
            break;\
        case 2:\
            _freq = CHANNEL2;\
            break;\
        case 3:\
            _freq = CHANNEL3;\
            break;\
        case 4:\
            _freq = CHANNEL4;\
            break;\
        case 5:\
            _freq = CHANNEL5;\
            break;\
        case 6:\
            _freq = CHANNEL6;\
            break;\
        case 7:\
            _freq = CHANNEL7;\
            break;\
        case 8:\
            _freq = CHANNEL8;\
            break;\
        case 9:\
            _freq = CHANNEL9;\
            break;\
        case 10:\
            _freq = CHANNEL10;\
            break;\
        case 11:\
            _freq = CHANNEL11;\
            break;\
        case 12:\
            _freq = CHANNEL12;\
            break;\
        case 13:\
            _freq = CHANNEL13;\
            break;\
        case 14:\
            _freq = CHANNEL14;\
            break;\
    }\
    _freq;\
});
```

the CHANNELNUM are constants values that i define in a enum with the frequenties values associated with the channel

Now my code works, or almost the getChannel does. With changeChannel ioctl return 0 but if i launch

```
iw interface info
```

The command show me always the same channel. 
Where is my error? Sorry for the English and thanks to all for the patience